# dockerfile how to run shopt -s extglob

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

## DO SOMETHING HERE

RUN /bin/bash -c shopt -s extglob && rm -rfv !(".env")
```

I am getting

```
Step 42/49 : RUN /bin/bash -c shopt -s extglob && rm -rfv !(".env")
 ---> Running in 5b4ceacb1908
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

HOw to run this command. I need this

Comment: All the answers are really bad and don't work. After an hour of investigating, I'm convinced we have to do this via a script.

Answer (score 0):

Every RUN line in your Dockerfile will launch a new container with a separate shell. The `extglob` shell option must be set before a line of input is parsed by the shell, so one way to go about this is to launch the shell with that option enabled:

```
RUN /bin/bash -O extglob -c 'rm -rfv !(".env")'
```

The main caveat is that you have to quote the command line as a string.

Comment: It worked for me using this approach using alpine as base and building over it.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend avoiding bash-specific syntax wherever possible.

In this case, the bash-specific glob pattern `!(.env)` means "every file except `.env`.  So you can accomplish this specific task by moving `.env` out of the way, deleting the whole directory, recreating it, and moving `.env` back; all without worrying about which shell expansion objects are set.

```sh
RUN cd .. \
 && mv the_dir/.env . \
 && rm -rf the_dir \
 && mkdir the_dir \
 && mv .env the_dir
```

You also might consider whether you need a broad `rm -rf` at all.  Because of Docker's layer system, the previous content of the directory is still "in the image".  If you use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) then the later stage will start from a clean slate, and you can `COPY` in whatever you need.

```sh
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster AS build
...
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY .env .
COPY --from=build ...
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The `RUN ... && rm -rf ... && ...` block  does the same thing the line in the question asks to do, using only standard tools.  It seems like that's the actual goal; `bash -c 'shopt ...'` is just a means to an end.

Comment: Sure, but people may have other reasons for which they want to have extglob support in their Dockerfiles.

Answer (score -3):

/bin/bash seems to work for "shopt -s extglob" part but not the other. Separate the lines like this:

```
 RUN /bin/bash -c shopt -s extglob  
 RUN /bin/bash -c rm -rfv !(".env")
```

or

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "shopt -s extglob && rm -rfv !(\".env\")"
```

Comment: neither of the proposed solutions works